# Open source tool to create a logo using google fonts / Lato

Tags: gimp, google-fonts, evolus-pencil

I am looking for an open source tool that I can use to create a text based logo.  I would like to use the Lato font from the Google Fonts family.  I have tried Gimp and Pencil Project but neither worked.   Any suggestions / recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logos are vector art so you should be using InkScape for this.